# Animate Auto Layout Constraints and Alpha on NSView

Tags: nsview, nsviewanimation

*Swift 3, iOS 10, macOS 10.12.4*

I am building an app that runs on both iOS and Mac. On the iOS side, I have successfully animated a `UIView`. When the user taps on something, a popup appears and animates into position. Here's my code inside the **tap** event:

```
self.popupConstraintX.constant = x
self.popupConstraintY.constant = y

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25 , delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
  self.graphPopup.alpha = 1.0
  self.layoutIfNeeded()

}, completion:nil)
```

In this case, `self` refers to a `UITableViewCell` that holds the `graphPopup`.

I have built the same thing on the Mac side, but I'm trying to animate `graphPopup` which is now an `NSView`. Here's what I have so far inside my **click** event:

```
self.popupConstraintX.constant = x
self.popupConstraintY.constant = y

self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()

NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({_ in
  self.graphPopup.alphaValue = 1.0
  
  //Indicate the duration of the animation
  NSAnimationContext.current().duration = 0.25
  NSAnimationContext.current().allowsImplicitAnimation = true
  self.view.updateConstraints()
  self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
  
}, completionHandler:nil)
```

Here `self` refers to the containing `NSViewController`. Nothing animates--not the position or the `alpha` of `graphPopup`. It just appears and disappears like it's on an Atari in 1985.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with my `NSView` animation?

---

**Update**

For posterity's sake, here is the working code as suggested by BJ (with a slight tweak to use the implicit animation context):

```
self.popupConstraintX.constant = x
self.popupConstraintY.constant = y

NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({context in
  context.duration = 0.25
  context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
  
  self.graphPopup.alphaValue = 1.0
  self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
  
}, completionHandler:nil)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The modification of `alphaValue` is happening before you have turned on implicit animation, so the alpha will not be animated. It's unclear to me whether that was intentional or not.

The view is not animating to the position given by the `popupConstraint`s, because you're not actually doing anything inside the animation block that would cause the view's frame to change. In order to trigger an implicit animation, you must not only update constraints; you must also ensure that the view's `frame` changes within the animation block. If you're using AutoLayout, this is usually done by calling `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded`.

**However**, because you updated the constraints and called `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` prior to the animation block, there are no additional frame changes left to make inside the block (unless there's something happening down in `updateConstraints()` which you haven't shown us.)

You should remove the first call to `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()`, or if it's still necessary, put it above the `popupConstraint` modifications. Then, when you call `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` within the animation block, a new frame will be set based on those changed constraints, and you should see animation happening.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

`animator()` is the key.

You can simply do like this:

```
 NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in

    //Indicate the duration of the animation
    context.duration = 0.25
    self.popupConstraintX.animator().constant = x
    self.popupConstraintY.animator().constant = y
    self.graphPopup.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
   
   }, completionHandler:nil)
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSAnimationContext.current()` to set the duration? the context of the animation is done for that, which in your case you are using `_ in`, should be `context in`, and you set the context.duration properly.

Comment: Thanks, @marcelosarquis for the context correction. I've updated the answer.