# NSView Animation not animating

Tags: swift, macos, animation, nsview

I'm trying to animate an NSView by changing the value of its leading constraint.

This is my constraint object:

`@IBOutlet weak var vModDatesLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!`

and the code I am using to animate its position:

```
@IBAction func getModDates(_ sender: Any) {
    
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in

        //Indicate the duration of the animation
        context.duration = 0.5
        vModDatesLeading.constant = 0
        vModDatesLeading.animator()
        vModDatesWrapper.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
       
       }, completionHandler:nil)
}
```

It is moving, but jumping, not animating. If this was iOS I would add:

`view.layoutIfNeeded()`

but that is not an option for NSView. I tried `layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()` but that did nada.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate Auto Layout Constraints and Alpha on NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903105/animate-auto-layout-constraints-and-alpha-on-nsview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly work in iOS these days, and don't think I've ever used NSAnimationContext. I did a little digging, and it looks like you need to add the line

`context.current.allowsImplicitAnimation = true`

inside the body of your runAnimationGroup closure.

### Edit:

I just noticed the line

```
vModDatesLeading.animator()
```

In your code. That doesn't do anything. The idea is that you should fetch an animator proxy for the object you are animating and apply your changes to that proxy. Thus your code should read:

```
NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in

    //Indicate the duration of the animation
    context.duration = 0.5
    vModDatesLeading.animator().constant = 0
    vModDatesWrapper.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
}
```

(Note that I haven't tested this. I **think** that would work without needing the `context.current.allowsImplicitAnimation = true`, but I'd have to test it to be sure.)

Comment: Is `NSAnimationContext.current` the same context as `context`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I was working with a slightly different example where `context` wasn't defined. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Either `context` or `NSAnimationContext.current` should work.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I've seen this but haven't had a chance to test it yet.

Comment: Do you need `vModDatesWrapper.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()`? Or is the answer the same as [Animate Auto Layout Constraints and Alpha on NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62954619)?

Comment: That was it. Thanks!